# PHP putenv equivalent in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I used to read environment variable from json file in core php using putenv. But now i switched to codeigniter. How can i read this file which resides in \assets( root of project)

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=config.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

`putenv()` is a PHP7 function and value exists until the current request ends and it doesn't make any sense for permanent availability.
For that we can create .htaccess(for Apache Server and if file not present) file inside root folder (Where index.php exists).

And we can add following code

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS config.json
</IfModule>
```

The variable will be available anywhere in application using code `$_SERVER['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']`

Comment: When i pronted $_SERVER['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] it output config.json. But that doesnt solve my problem. Do i need to write putenv again to read the json file. I actually writing this code for adding calender event

Comment: $file = FCPATH.$_SERVER['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'];
if(is_file($file)){
 $jsonContents = file_get_contents($file);
 $array = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
 var_dump($array);
}